# using @variable to calculate relevance

Tags: mysql

i want to order mysql search results by relevance.
The table fields are:

```
id, title, teaser
```

my query is:

```
SELECT id, title, teaser, @var := 0, if(teaser like '%str%', @var := @var + 1, @var), if(title like '%str%', @var := @var + 1, @var), @var as relevance FROM `table` where title like '%str%' ORDER BY relevance
```

well, but "relevance" is NULL... it should be at least 1 (because i am looking for matches with title like "str")

What i want:
if title contains "str", @var should count up.
if teaser also contains "str", @var should count up.

then i want to order the results by var desc in order to get the most relevant matches first...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the relevance per row, when i am understanding you idea correctly

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int,title varchar(10),teaser varchar(19) )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'str','str'),(2,'str','abc'),(3,'abc','aAX')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     id,
>     title,
>     teaser,
>     IF(teaser LIKE '%str%',
>         @var:=1,
>         @var := 0),
>     IF(title LIKE '%str%',
>         @var:=@var + 1,
>         @var),
>     @var AS relevance
> FROM
>     `table1`, (SELECT @var:=0) t1
> WHERE
>     title LIKE '%str%'
> ORDER BY relevance DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title | teaser | IF(teaser LIKE '%str%',@var:=1,@var := 0) | IF(title LIKE '%str%', @var:=@var + 1, @var) | relevance
> -: | :---- | :----- | ----------------------------------------------------------: | :----------------------------------------------------------- | :--------
>  1 | str   | str    |                                                           1 | 2                                                            | 2        
>  2 | str   | abc    |                                                           0 | 1                                                            | 1
> ```

But you can do it without variables

> ```
> SELECT 
>     id,
>     title,
>     teaser
>     ,(IF(teaser LIKE '%str%',1,0) + IF(title LIKE '%str%',1,0)) AS relevance
> FROM
>     `table1`
>  WHERE
>     title LIKE '%str%'
> ORDER BY relevance DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title | teaser | relevance
> -: | :---- | :----- | --------:
>  1 | str   | str    |         2
>  2 | str   | abc    |         1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=94671316e96e2f7bf1787727f8daac3c)*

Comment: @user7213923 if you have a huge database and mor search words, take a look at fulltext indexes

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a variable for this, just add the likes together:

```
SELECT id, title, teaser,
    (teaser like '%str%') + (title like '%str%') as relevance
FROM `table`
where title like '%str%'
ORDER BY relevance
```

But while the title check is in your where clause, you could just `+ 1` instead.

(Modifying a variable in a select is deprecated now, since there are better ways to do most of the things that was a workaround for.)